# Why are some CentOS 5 boxes still vulnerable to ShellShock after upgrading Bash?

Tags: centos, security, bash, yum, rpm

I have two CentOS 5.10 boxen where I have upgraded `bash` to the latest version.  However, in one of the boxes, `bash` is still vulnerable to `CVE-2014-7169` (I am using the test from [this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/631450/9979)).

Any ideas on why one machine is OK and the other one isn't?  What can I check for?

What I've checked already:

1- Ensure both machines are running the same OS (same output on both):

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 5.10 (Final)
```

2- Ensure I have the same version of `bash` (same output on both):

```
# rpm -qi bash
Name        : bash                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 3.2                               Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 33.el5_10.4                   Build Date: Thu 25 Sep 2014 08:58:19 PM UTC
Install Date: Sat 27 Sep 2014 02:07:07 PM UTC      Build Host: sclbuild-c5.centos.org
Group       : System Environment/Shells     Source RPM: bash-3.2-33.el5_10.4.src.rpm
Size        : 5235475                          License: GPLv2+
Signature   : DSA/SHA1, Fri 26 Sep 2014 02:11:39 AM UTC, Key ID a8a447dce8562897
```

3- Double check that the binary is OK signature wise (same output on both):

```
# rpm -V bash
```

(there was no output from this command, indicating the binary signatures checked out)

4- Check that the binaries are in fact the same versions (as suggested by Cyrus in the comments): (same output on both machines)

```
# rpm -qf /bin/bash
bash-3.2-33.el5_10.4
```

5- Check the size of the binaries

```
# ls -l /bin/bash    (Good machine)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 801816 Sep 25 20:55 /bin/bash

# ls -l /bin/bash    (Bad/vulnerable machine)
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 768952 Sep 25 20:55 /bin/bash
```

Notice that the file sizes are different.

6- Actually test for the vulnerability

```
# ## on the good machine
# env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"; cat echo
date
cat: echo: No such file or directory

# ## on the bad/vulnerable machine
# env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"; cat echo
date
Sat Sep 27 13:44:36 UTC 2014
```

Comment: Hmm, on a recently updated i386 CentOS 5.10 box, I see the same package info as you, but my bash executable size is different from both of yours: `$ ls -l /bin/bash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 736348 Sep 25 17:03 /bin/bash`  My bash is not vulnerable to 7169 after the update.

Comment: There are tests supplied by Red Hat - do they actually show your "bad" machine as vulnerable?  Both tests are defined here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1212303

Comment: @cjc my box is 64-bit so the sizes will be different

Comment: @OzSolomon: `rpm -qf /bin/bash` Is the output the same?

Comment: @Cyrus - Both machines show the same result for -qf.  I updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: @JoshuaMiller I can confirm that the second machine is vulnerable using RedHat's test.  I'll update the question to show the actual result.

Comment: This doesn't explain why there's a problem, but for sanity, can you grab the RPM from, say, http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/updates/x86_64/RPMS/ and force install using that?  I would keep that vulnerable copy of /bin/bash around to do forensics later, if you feel like it.

Comment: Perhaps you've found another shell that is vulnerable, check what sh is linking to with `ls -l /bin/sh` . This is why I updated my answer on how to test, to specifically use bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could be a false positive - Make sure the 'echo' file does not exist from an earlier test on your bad machine, then retest.

Failing that, could also be a false negative - Check you can touch a file on your good machine, then retest.

Comment: You nailed it!  There was a file called 'echo' in the directory where I did the tests (probably from before upgrading).  I deleted it and it worked fine.